# 「自分でも」 and 「くらい」 what's it being used for here?

Tags: grammar, meaning

Ok, so I have spent some time trying to find so explanations of the grammar used in this sentence but I can't seem to quite understand what the 「自分でも」 and 「くらい」 are doing in this sentence.

> 「**自分でも**不思議な**くらい**に落ち着いた心で、目の前の美少女に静かに尋ねた」

My best translation of the sentence is: "with a strangely calm heart, I quietly asked the beautiful girl before my eyes."

here's some of sentences before to give some context

> 俺は、頭で教えるよりも先にその子を突き飛ばしていた。
>   そして・・。
>   ・・自分でも不思議なくらいに落ち着いた心で、目の前の美少女に静かに尋ねた。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> with a strangely composed heart, I calmly asked the beautiful girl before my eyes

***自分でも : oneself / even I .*** 
 It was strange even for himself, since he thought he shouldn't be feel that composed.

***不思議なくらい : strangely / oddly enough / to the extent of being strange*** 
Just 不思議 means strange/mysterious, adding くらい modify the meaning into above explanations

Answer (score 3):

It's a common rhetorical phrase, though not idiomatic, to express total unexpectedness.

> 自分でも（不思議な／びっくりする／驚く／よくわからない etc.）（ほど／くらい）

It tells that what you did or felt was out of your own expectation. You could translate it like "so — that even myself don't (didn't) know why".